# VMware ESXi 5.0.0 hardware monitoring

Tags: monitoring, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

Here is my config:

- Supermicro X7DBU;
- 3ware 9650 RAID Controller - driver installed, I use it as main datastore;
- managing the hypervisor with VMware vSphere Client 5.0.0 on Windows 2003 Server;

I have read that under the Configuration Tab on the client, Under Health Status, I should be able to see more hardware information than is displayed on the screenshot below.

[image: VMware Configuration tab screnshot]

What I want is very simple - a way to monitor the hardware status of the server as well as the RAID array state. Now, I have no way to know if a drive has failed, if the temperature is high, etc. I managed to install 3ware RAID CLI (`tw_cli`) and possibly this would help, but it solves the problem only partially.

The best solution should be a free one, as I have only this server and no money to spend on it.

How I can approach this?

Comment: The ammount of information that is showed is highly dependent on you buying/having hardware that is explicitly [supported](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php) by Vmware.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're out of luck.  Normally the vendor would provide a CIM driver (or it's there by default for IBM, Dell, etc.) to enable hardware monitoring, but according to Supermicro's [FAQ](http://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=14449), they're not planning on releasing one.